# How to iterate through a Hashie::Mash?

Tags: ruby

I'd like to loop through the keys and values of a Hashie::Mash.

Here's my attempt to do so:

```
html = "Just look at these subscriptions!"
client.subscriptions.each do |sub|
  html << sub.each do |key, value|
      html << key.to_s
      html << " = "
      html << value.to_s
  end
end
```

It returns the following error:

"Can't convert Hashie::Mash to String (Hashie::Mash#to_str gives NilClass)"

I've tried `sub.keys.to_s` and `sub.values.to_s` which produced `["key1", "key2", "key3"]`, `["value1", "value2", "value3"]`, but I'm looking for something that shows the pairs matched, as they are in a hash, or like ["key1: value1", "key2: value2", "key3: value3"].  Is there a way to do this without zipping together separate arrays?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sub.to_hash` shows something that is *exactly* like a hash. :) Then you can do whatever you can do with a hash; like

```
html << sub.to_hash.to_s
```

or you could do what you're doing, in a bit more Rubyish way:

```
html << sub.map { |key, value| "#{key} = #{value}" }.join(", ")
```

However, your real problem is in `html << sub.each ...`: `each` returns the collection being iterated, so you're doing `html << sub`; and this fails. Your code would work if you just removed `html <<` from that line, since the concatenation is taken care of inside the `each` loop.

Comment: Thank you, that was *exactly* what I was looking for!  `sub.to_hash.to_s` produced `{"key1" => "value1", "key2" => "value2", "key3" => "value3"}`